# Adding WPF content dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, dynamically-generated

What I would like to do is to create a class that contains for instance a Label and Text box. It can differs. I would like to create and add this obj dynamically.

I would like to bind that data to its properties and of-course show the changes immediately:

My steps are:

1. Create Class e.g. WpfObject
2. Create new Label
3. Create new TextBox
4. Create property
5. Constructor with or without parameters
6. Constructor contains databinding settings

I followed WPF tutorial on wpf-tutorial page also checked msdn for hints,  and tried to do analogically and  not to forgot any step . Of course I tried to google where the problem can be.

By debugging I just found that onPropertyChanged resp. PropertyChanged still returns null.

Well I do not know for what I have to look. I tried to learn something from another issues stated here, or on the web but probably I understand something wrong or forgot something.

So would like to ask for some hint, or help.

Here I am adding my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    List<infoObject> LinfoObjectList = new List<infoObject>();

    private void btnAddBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        infoObject theObject = new infoObject("theinfo");
        LinfoObjectList.Add(theObject);
        mainGrid.Children.Add(theObject.AddLabel());
        mainGrid.Children.Add(theObject.AddTextbox());
    }

    private void btnCustomBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(var item in LinfoObjectList)
        {
            item.ChangeInfoObject();
        }
    }
}

public class infoObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    string _sTheText;

    string STheText
    {
        set { _sTheText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("sTheText");
        }

        get { return _sTheText; }
    }

    Label theLabel = new Label();
    TextBox theTextBox = new TextBox();

    int i;

    public infoObject(string _objectName){
        STheText = " ";
        i = 0;
        theLabel.Width = 100;
        theLabel.Height = 25;
        theLabel.Content = _objectName;

        theTextBox.Width = 100;
        theTextBox.Height = 30;
        theTextBox.Text = STheText.ToString();


        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("sTheText");
        theTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, binding);
    }

    public void ChangeInfoObject()
    {
        STheText = "textWasChanged"+i.ToString();
        i = +1;
    }

    public Label AddLabel()
    {
        return this.theLabel;
    }

    public TextBox AddTextbox()
    {
        return this.theTextBox;
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

edit: 
to clarify what I would like to do:

I would like to make some library or sth. like that and  that in future I will be able to create textboxes , labels, buttons for for instance each of element I have stored in list or elsewhere.

So I just will add e.g.  Element.add( starting position , left margin ,topmargin, root-name , otherparams) and it will create these mentioned dynamically and I get rid of positioning, putting into grid, for each element.

Comment: What you ask for sounds much like what DataTemplates are for. Look into some tutorials about how to use (data)templates in WPF...

Comment: Read the [Control Authoring Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview) and [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview) articles on MS Docs.

Comment: Well , probably I am not aware of the fact how can this solve my problem. 
I would like to create different object dynamically according to different input. 
From my point of view , I am really not sure why to use this instead of some class or an library . 
Could you please explain or show how to solve my task by DataTemplates ?. 

I just want the get rid off creating labels and text boxes manually because sometimes is necessary to create e.g. 30 or more labels and textboxes manualy bind them ,position them ....

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you are trying to do. In my quick read of your question, it seems to be all you might need is a user control and not a fully custom control approach which usually can be avoided and if required is probably subclassing an exiting one and adding the feature you need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977511/wpf-usercontrol-or-customcontrol

Comment: Well, I just want to create/change class obj as it is. Obviously it is not working. I am not sure why. I did read topics here, in stackoverflow where people wanted to solve binding changes during the program run by clicking on a button for instance. 
But they have implemented such object like button, label , textbox in WPF xaml file - manually and they added e.g. Content={Binding Path=nameofproperty} manually . I did tutorials on wpf-tutorial but none were similar to mine. 
What I tried many times is to add that component or group of comp. dynamically on_load or after clicking a button

Comment: Your property name is not correct, this is case sensitive. OnPropertyChanged("sTheText") should be OnPropertyChanged("STheText") it's the name of your public property ;)